# How do I replace text on website only if the userscript sees a trigger word?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want my userscript to replace word "A", on a page, with word "B", ***unless*** word "C" is present.
If "C" is present, then I want to replace "A" with "D" instead.

For example,

1. Normally, it would replace `Cat` with `Feline`.
2. But, if the userscript sees the word `Kitten` on the webpage, it would instead change `Cat` to `Meow`.
3. Obviously, it should do the same with multiple other word sets, if I want it to.

I found [this old userscript written by Joe Simmons](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/41369); see the relevant code, below. Although it works extremely well, How do I add the conditional functionality?

```
(function () { 'use strict';
    var words = {
        // Syntax: 'Search word' : 'Replace word',
        'your a':       'you\'re a',
        'imo':          'in my opinion',
        'im\\*o':       'matching an asterisk, not a wildcard',
        '/\\bD\\b/g':   '[D]',

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        '': ''
    };

    var regexs = [],
        replacements = [],
        tagsWhitelist = ['PRE', 'BLOCKQUOTE', 'CODE', 'INPUT', 'BUTTON', 'TEXTAREA'],
        rIsRegexp = /^\/(.+)\/([gim]+)?$/,
        word, text, texts, i, userRegexp;

    // prepareRegex by JoeSimmons
    // used to take a string and ready it for use in new RegExp()
    function prepareRegex (string) {
        return string.replace (/([\[\]\^\&\$\.\(\)\?\/\\\+\{\}\|])/g, '\\$1');
    }

    // function to decide whether a parent tag will have its text replaced or not
    function isTagOk (tag) {
        return tagsWhitelist.indexOf (tag) === -1;
    }

    delete words['']; // so the user can add each entry ending with a comma,
    // I put an extra empty key/value pair in the object.
    // so we need to remove it before continuing

    // convert the 'words' JSON object to an Array
    for (word in words) {
        if (typeof word === 'string' && words.hasOwnProperty (word) ) {
            userRegexp = word.match (rIsRegexp);

            // add the search/needle/query
            if (userRegexp) {
                regexs.push (
                    new RegExp (userRegexp[1], 'g')
                );
            }
            else {
                regexs.push (
                    new RegExp (prepareRegex (word)
                        .replace (/\\?\*/g, function (fullMatch) {
                            return fullMatch === '\\*' ? '*' : '[^ ]*';
                        } ),
                        'g'
                    )
                );
            }

            // add the replacement
            replacements.push(words[word]);
        }
    }

    // do the replacement
    texts = document.evaluate ('//body//text()[ normalize-space(.) != "" ]', document, null, 6, null);
    for (i = 0; text = texts.snapshotItem (i); i += 1) {
        if (isTagOk (text.parentNode.tagName) ) {
            regexs.forEach (function (value, index) {
                text.data = text.data.replace (value, replacements[index]);
            } );
        }
    }
} () );
```

Comment: Clarify: Is the trigger word anywhere on the page, or must it be in the same text block as the word to replace?  If the latter, show the HTML structure of both trigger and target word.

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse the execution order by creating a kitten filter that would trigger before the cat filter.

```
var words = {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Syntax: 'Search word' : 'Replace word',
    '/(kitten.*)?Cat(.*kitten)?/gi' : 'Meow',
    'Cat'                           : 'Feline',
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
};
```

It's certainly less annoying than implementing a callback.